# Securing nestjs api with identityserver4 using only Introspection Endpoint

Tags: identityserver4, nestjs, openid-connect

I have an `identityserver4` project which is working fine and everything is running correctly with a `.net api`.

My real question is can i use my token in `nestjs api` and validate the token using `IdentityServer4` Introspection Endpoint.

For example my `javascript` client login to the identity provider and send the token to the `nestjs api` and from there i send the token from api to `IdentityServer4` Introspection Endpoint to validate the token.

Is there any problem using this route. any security or something?